`Desktop` context menu "Open in Terminal" has disappeared
Like the title says, from Desktop, the context menu displayed upon a right-click used to have "Open in Terminal" but it has disappeared.
I can still use right-click "Open in Terminal" from inside Files/nautilus when there is a file system browsing window displayed.  My problem is that I also want to do it from the Desktop wallpaper.  Please advise.
Addendum...
Context: 20.04 Focal Fossa with no significant customizations
Changes to the system recently: The only changes I recall are apt update and apt full-upgrade.

Please [edit] your question and give us some context. What Ubuntu are you using? What desktop environment? Gnome? XFCE? Something else? What changed in the meantime? Did you just wake up and it was gone or did you update/install something?

Check with your package manager if you have the nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal installed. Maybe it needs an update. There's also two Gnome shell extensions for that if you have icons disabled on desktop:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/721/gnome-shell-open-terminal/
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1828/gnome-shell-open-terminal/
Test if any of those extensions help because they cover different versions of the shell.
